# How can I type one item at the time from ListBox items using Timer?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, listbox

I am able to add few items to ListBox which later I need to type separately by using timer.

This is how I'm using timer to type all items at once when my timer ticks. But how can I type one line at the time when my timer ticks?

```
private void Interval(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (nudPlusMinus.Value == 0)
    {
        tmrInterval.Interval = int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        tmrInterval.Interval = random.Next(int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString()) - int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString()) + int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()));
    }

    foreach (var item in lbMessage.Items)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(item.ToString() + "{enter}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create counter:

```
private int listBoxItemCounter = 0;

private void Interval(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //setting interval

   if(listBoxItemCounter<lbMessage.Items.Count) 
   {
       SendKeys.Send(lbMessage.Items[listBoxItemCounter].ToString()+"{enter}");
       listBoxItemCounter++; 
   }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! I was thinking of using count by I wasn't sure how to do this. Thanks m8!